# Как записать строку в файл?

Tags: php, файлы, filewriter

Доброго дня друзья.
Сел за PHP и немного не понял, почему при следующем коде:

```
$file = fopen("test.txt", "r+");
fwrite($file, "TestText\n");
fwrite($file, "TestOne\n")
```

в файл записывается TestTextTestOne без переносов строки.
Знаю про file_put_content(), однако хочу принципиально понять в чём проблема.
Так же: как узнать кол-во строк в файлике?

Comment: Потому что смотрите файл не в том редакторе :)

Comment: В `Windows` перенос строк определяется двумя символами `\r\n`

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы не было проблем с разными кодами переноса строки с разных ОС, то лучше использовать соответствующий код переноса строки (PHP_EOL) вместо "\n":

```
$file = fopen("test.txt", "r+");
fwrite($file, "TestText" . PHP_EOL);
```

Comment: кореектнее использовать http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.constants.php#constant.php-eol - как код переноса

Comment: @MaksymPrus, благодарю. Исправил.

Comment: вместо "+" нужно использовать "." для конкатенации, это жt не javascript